# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse problema com firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Eu comecei recentemente a trabalhar com Bootstrap e estou a tentar criar uma `navbar`.

O problema é que a `navbar` aparenta ser normal até diminuirmos o tamanho da janela onde ela dá `collapse` como devia ser, mas o botão `toggle` só funciona no Google Chrome:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">RaminhaGest</a>            
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">F</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PS: tentei por o codigo no JSFiddle mas nao funcionou como deve de ser...

Comment: Cara explica melhor como poderia ser essa solução.

Comment: O toggle é feito via javascript, se não está funcionando no Firefox deve ser porque há um problema no JS em relação ao FF.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o meu problema:

Eu só tinha um item na lista e, como as animações do Google Chrome e do Firefox são ligeiramente diferentes, isto não aparecia correctamente.

Com mais itens já funciona direito.